# tex4ebook or tex4ht: optional arguments for \title not supported

Tags: titles, tex4ht, tex4ebook

Sample code:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\title[Short]{Long}
\maketitle

Hello

\end{document}
```

compiled with tex4ebook, the optional argument of `\title` is mistakenly proceeded (the title being `Short]Long`).

Comment: That looks like a bug. The maintainer of tex4ht is active on this site, so he will see your question eventually and he might be able to fix the bug. In the meantime you can always manually edit the `.epub` file to correct the title (unzip, edit, rezip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tex4ebook` redefines the `\title` command in order to save it's contents in a macro that can be used in the metadata generation. The standard classes don't use optional arguments for `\title`, so `tex4ebook` don't expect that. It is not a good idea to redefine the standard LaTeX macros with a different number of arguments in general.

Anyway, I've updated `tex4ebook` to handle this case, here is the updated `tex4ebook.sty` package:

```
% Package tex4ebook. Author Michal Hoftich <michal.h21@gmail.com>
% This package is subject of LPPL license, version 1.3 
\ProvidesPackage{tex4ebook}[2016/03/31 version 0.1d]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
% Command for generating NCX file. Hard work is odne in the file
% tex4ebook.4ht
\def\ncxtable{}
% Command for generating OPF file 
\def\opftable{}

%Declare RFC3066 language code for babel language name
\def\DeclareLanguage#1#2{%
\csgdef{rfclang#1}{#2}%
}
\def\GetLanguage{%
\ifx\bbl@main@language\@undefined en-US%  
\else%
\ifcsdef{rfclang\bbl@main@language}{\csuse{rfclang\bbl@main@language}}{}%
\fi%
}

\DeclareLanguage{UKenglish}{en-GB}
\DeclareLanguage{USenglish}{en-US}
\DeclareLanguage{acadian}{fr}
\DeclareLanguage{albanian}{sq}
\DeclareLanguage{american}{en-US}
\DeclareLanguage{amharic}{am}
\DeclareLanguage{arabic}{ar}
\DeclareLanguage{armenian}{hy}
\DeclareLanguage{australian}{en-US}
\DeclareLanguage{austrian}{de}
\DeclareLanguage{basque}{eu}
\DeclareLanguage{bengali}{bn}
\DeclareLanguage{brazilian}{pt}
\DeclareLanguage{brazil}{pt}
\DeclareLanguage{breton}{br}
\DeclareLanguage{british}{en-GB}
\DeclareLanguage{bulgarian}{bg}
\DeclareLanguage{canadian}{en-US}
\DeclareLanguage{canadien}{fr}
\DeclareLanguage{catalan}{ca}
\DeclareLanguage{croatian}{hr}
\DeclareLanguage{czech}{cs-CZ}
\DeclareLanguage{danish}{da}
\DeclareLanguage{divehi}{dv}
\DeclareLanguage{dutch}{nl}
\DeclareLanguage{english}{en}
\DeclareLanguage{esperanto}{eo}
\DeclareLanguage{estonian}{et}
\DeclareLanguage{finnish}{f\/i}
\DeclareLanguage{francais}{fr}
\DeclareLanguage{french}{fr}
\DeclareLanguage{galician}{gl}
\DeclareLanguage{germanb}{de}
\DeclareLanguage{german}{de}
\DeclareLanguage{greek}{el}
\DeclareLanguage{hebrew}{he}
\DeclareLanguage{hindi}{hi}
\DeclareLanguage{hungarian}{hu}
\DeclareLanguage{icelandic}{is}
\DeclareLanguage{interlingua}{ia}
\DeclareLanguage{irish}{ga}
\DeclareLanguage{italian}{it}
\DeclareLanguage{kannada}{kn}
\DeclareLanguage{khmer}{km}
\DeclareLanguage{korean}{ko}
\DeclareLanguage{lao}{lo}
\DeclareLanguage{latin}{la}
\DeclareLanguage{latvian}{lv}
\DeclareLanguage{lithuanian}{lt}
\DeclareLanguage{lowersorbian}{dsb}
\DeclareLanguage{magyar}{hu}
\DeclareLanguage{malayalam}{ml}
\DeclareLanguage{marathi}{mr}
\DeclareLanguage{naustrian}{de}
\DeclareLanguage{newzealand}{en}
\DeclareLanguage{ngerman}{de}
\DeclareLanguage{norsk}{no}
\DeclareLanguage{norwegiannynorsk}{nn}
\DeclareLanguage{nynorsk}{no}
\DeclareLanguage{occitan}{oc}
\DeclareLanguage{oldchurchslavonic}{cu}
\DeclareLanguage{persian}{fa}
\DeclareLanguage{polish}{pl-PL}
\DeclareLanguage{polutonikogreek}{el}
\DeclareLanguage{portuges}{pt}
\DeclareLanguage{portuguese}{pt}
\DeclareLanguage{romanian}{ro}
\DeclareLanguage{romansh}{rm}
\DeclareLanguage{russian}{ru}
\DeclareLanguage{samin}{se}
\DeclareLanguage{sanskrit}{sa}
\DeclareLanguage{scottish}{gd}
\DeclareLanguage{serbian}{sr}
\DeclareLanguage{serbo-croatian}{sh}
\DeclareLanguage{slovak}{sk}
\DeclareLanguage{slovene}{sl}
\DeclareLanguage{slovenian}{sl}
\DeclareLanguage{spanish}{es}
\DeclareLanguage{swedish}{sv}
\DeclareLanguage{tamil}{ta}
\DeclareLanguage{telugu}{te}
\DeclareLanguage{thai}{th}
\DeclareLanguage{tibetan}{bo}
\DeclareLanguage{turkish}{tr}
\DeclareLanguage{turkmen}{tk}
\DeclareLanguage{ukrainian}{uk}
\DeclareLanguage{uppersorbian}{hsb}
\DeclareLanguage{urdu}{ur}
\DeclareLanguage{vietnamese}{vi}
\DeclareLanguage{welsh}{cy}

\AtEndDocument{%
\ncxtable
\opftable
}

% Default empty values
\def\Title{Unnamed}
\def\Author{Anonymous}

% We need to save values of title, author etc.
\let\origtitle\title

% normal \title
\newcommand\tftitle[1]{%
  \origtitle{#1}%
  \let\Title\@title%
}

% \title with optional argument
\newcommand\tfopttitle[2][]{%
  \origtitle[#1]{#2}%
  \let\Title\@title%
}

% some classes (amsart) define \title command with optional argument
\renewcommand\title{%
\@ifnextchar[\tfopttitle\tftitle%
}

\let\origauthor\author
\renewcommand\author[1]{%
  \origauthor{#1}%
  \let\Author\@author
}
%\let\Author\@author
\let\Date\today
\let\origdate\date
\renewcommand\date[1]{%
  \origdate{#1}%
  \let\Date\@date%
}
%}

\newcommand\coverimage[2][]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please also modify `\author` to handle an optional argument? Thanks.

Comment: @Yai0Phah I've just fixed the `\author` command in `tex4ebook`

Comment: If I add a `\thanks` command like `\thanks{Supported by blah}` with document class `amsart`, then there will be a hyperlinked `0` on top of the title. Is that an assumed behavior?

Comment: @Yai0Phah I hope it will be fixed in the new update of TeX4ht in TeX Live.